# Hide a rows and/or columns using formulas

Tags: google-sheets, formula, rows, show-hide

Is it possible to conditionally hide rows and/or columns using formulas but NOT the API?

Example:

```
=IF(A1=0,HIDEROW(1),SHOWROW(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HIDEROW` and `SHOWROW` are not native Google Spreadsheets functions and with that and *using formulas but NOT the API* I am not sure what you want, though the answer is likely ‘No’ regardless.

Alternatives may include a Google Apps Script, hiding the row *content* rather than the row itself (say with conditional formatting) and filtering the data – ie a copy of only the part you want visible. This might be with FILTER. For example with `0` and `1` alternating in A1:A4 of Sheet1 and `B1` series filled in B1 to B4 then in A1 of another sheet:

```
=IF(F1=2,FILTER(Sheet1!B1:B4,NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A1:A4))),FILTER(Sheet1!B1:B4,Sheet1!A1:A4=F1))
```

Should show B1 … B4 in that other sheet when F1 in that sheet is `2`, just B2 and B4 when `1` and just B1 and B3 when `0`.